# Plotting over existing plot

Tags: plot

I am wondering if it is possible to plot over CoolProp plotting function.

```
def plot_logph():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    y = np.array([100000,150000])
    x = np.array([600,800])
    plt.plot(x,y) #this is irellevant
    plot = PropertyPlot('HEOS::R290', 'PH', unit_system='EUR', tp_limits='ACHP')
    plot.calc_isolines(CoolProp.iQ, num=11)
    plot.calc_isolines(CoolProp.iT, num=25)
    plot.calc_isolines(CoolProp.iSmass, num=15)
    plot.plot(x,y)
    plot.show()
```

Whit this code next error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'PropertyPlot' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

The "plot" in your example is an instance of the PropertyPlot class which contains a matplotlib figure. To get the axis of the matplotlib figure you have to use:

```
plot.axis
```

And here you can plot what ever you want.

The full code example:

```
def plot_logph():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    y = np.array([1,5])
    x = np.array([600,800])
    plot = PropertyPlot('HEOS::R290', 'PH', unit_system='EUR', tp_limits='ACHP')
    plot.calc_isolines(CoolProp.iQ, num=11)
    plot.calc_isolines(CoolProp.iT, num=25)
    plot.calc_isolines(CoolProp.iSmass, num=15)
    plot.axis.plot(x,y)
    plot.show()
```